# How would I redirect both Standard output and Standard input of a command to a text file in one line?

Tags: bash, redirect

How would I redirect both Standard output and Standard input of a command to a text file in one line, and would the Standard input of a command such as "ls" be "ls", and if I redirected the standard input of ls to a file, would these characters appear in the file?

Comment: `ls` doesn't use its standard input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect both input and output, just use both redirections:

```
command < inputfile > outputfile
```

If the command doesn't read from its standard input, then the input redirection will have no effect. For instance, `ls` doesn't use its input, it just processes command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `script` command

Input

```
$ script
Script started, file is typescript
sh-4.1$ ls
bar.txt  baz.txt  foo.txt  typescript
sh-4.1$ exit
exit
Script done, file is typescript
```

Output

```
$ cat typescript
Script started on Sat Dec 27 13:49:33 2014
sh-4.1$ ls
bar.txt  baz.txt  foo.txt  typescript
sh-4.1$ exit
exit

Script done on Sat Dec 27 13:49:40 2014
```

[explainshell.com - script](http://explainshell.com/explain/1/script)